# create a path between the source and the destination in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I want to simulate an algorithm using the MATLAB. This algorithm is designed to find the optimal path among different path in order to be used for routing. The algorithm starts at a specific node (source) then move to a node that is a neighbor to the source node and so on until it reach the destination. I have a n by n matrix (n is the number of nodes) that contains 0 and 1 that is used to determine if the node is neighbor or not to another node (it will have a value of 1 if two nodes are neighbors). so how I can create the different paths from the source to the destination?

Comment: please tell us what you have  tried

Answer (score 0):

That's related with math's theory of graphs. It is familiar to you?

I would say using the BFS's algorithm is going to be the easier way. Between it's applications you find " Finding the shortest path between two nodes u and v (with path length measured by number of edges) ". You can find some theory about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search moreover the algorithm in pseudocode done.

If it isn't quite good for your purpose, you can move to the best available one: Dijkstra's algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm ). But I don't think you need something that sophisticated.

Also I would like to remind you that Matlab isn't the best choice when you have to do loop's stuff, since it somehow is time consuming on it.

I hope this helps.